# Using "indexOfObject:" in value expression for Core Data mapping model

Tags: objective-c, macos, core-data, icloud, core-data-migration

I need to migrate my core data model to replace an ordered relationship with a normal one to support iCloud. I've created an mapping model and tried to maintain the order by adding a new attribute "index" and using "*`FUNCTION($source.project.tasks, "indexOfObject:" , $source)`*" to get the old index. ($source.project.tasks should be an ordered set. The relationship between my entities "Project" and "Tasks" looks like this: tasks <-->> project) Unfortunately, this doesn't work. The app crashes at launch (EXC_BAD_ACCESS).

I'm not sure if this is the right way. Is there a way to make my approach work or is there a better way?

[image: Mapping Model]

**Edit:** $source.project.tasks returns an fault error message:
`Relationship 'tasks' fault on managed object (0x1019f9130)`

I've created an NSManagedObject category with an method "indexOfTask:" to log the object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a solution: All methods used by `FUNCTION(...)` need to return an id value, so I created a category for NSManagedObject and added this method:

```
- (NSNumber *)getIndexOfTask {
    NSUInteger index = [(NSOrderedSet *)[[(CTask *)self project] tasks] indexOfObject:self];
    if (index == NSNotFound)
        return @0;
    else
        return [NSNumber numberWithInteger:index];
}
```

This method returns the index as NSNumber and can be used by `FUNCTION(...)`:

```
FUNCTION($source, "getIndexOfTask").intValue
```

Answer (score 0):

**First idea**: try using another name (not `index`). It looks like it has a special meaning. How about `sequence`?

**Second idea**: do a two-step migration.

In an interim step, you just add the index. You iterate through all ordered sets and set the index and save. Then you do the second migration eliminating the ordered set altogether.

(*There should be a multiple store strategy that you can use to be on the safe side and go back to the old or interim data if something goes wrong.*)

Comment: changing the name doesn't help. I've also found out, that ".project.tasks" returns an fault. I'm not sure why it does that, but I'm sure my approach would work, if this is fixed.